# Await on stream to pulse x time before continuing

Tags: dart, future, dart-async

Simple dart problem, got a stream

```
Stream<Event>
```

I subscribe to in a unit test. Would like something like this:

```
stream.listen(listener)
await listenerBeenNotified5Times
expect(result,expectation)
```

I know expectAsync can be used to make sure the notification happens 5 times, but I want to wait to pause the execution until 5 events have been streamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var s = stream.take(5);
var subscription = s.listen(listener);
await susciption.asFuture;
```

or

```
await stream.take(5).toList();
```

Comment: That works, but only if you don't care about events after the first 5. The original question didn't specify what should happen to the listen after the five first events, so this is a good guess.

Comment: thank you as always Günter, this works for the test I needed.